# How can I disable Rickroll in Visual Studio Code even if it is not installed?

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I try to compile an HTML code in my visual studio code, the rickroll begins even if the extension is already uninstalled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [Details section](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Woohaik.vscode-rickroll) [of the extension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ), it does modify the `desktop.main.css` file, so in order to remove the rickroll you have to run the command `Rickroll remove Rick` from the command palette. Done that, you should be able to uninstall the extension and reload the window.

Edit:
If the problem persists be sure to have fully deleted, in the `VSCode_Installation_Folder/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.css` file, the code between `/*ext-vscode-rickroll-start*/` and `/*ext-vscode-rickroll-end*/`; then, after making sure you've uninstalled the extension, reload the window by the command `Developer: Reload Window`

Comment: Yeah, I did that and the rickroll stoped but only less than 1 min.

Comment: So it didn't stop? Did you do as the uninstall section mentioned? That is, using the command and then restarting the window after having uninstalled the extension?

Comment: Yeah I did that also but it keeps returning whenever I try to code.

Comment: Then try to do it manually: go to the vscode installation folder, more specifically, go in  the`VSCode_Installation_Folder/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/` folder, here you'd find `workbench.desktop.main.css`. Find and delete the part between `/*ext-vscode-rickroll-start*/` and `/*ext-vscode-rickroll-end*/`. Then, reload your window in vs code by using the `Developer: Reload Window` command. I'll update the answer shortly

Comment: If the problem is solved, consider marking the answer with a ✓, to better help others

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find these lines /*ext-vscode-rickroll-start*/ and /*ext-vscode-rickroll-end*/ at workbench.desktop.main.css.

Answer (score 0):

If you only uninstall the extension and the rickroll has already begun, that means the CSS has been modified already, so the background will stay there. because the extension works by editing the CSS of the editor.

To remove the CSS, you need to run the command:

```
Rickroll remove Rick
```

But in order to access the command `Rickroll remove Rick` the extension must be installed. And since this command does not deactivate the "listener" that triggers the Rickroll it will be triggered again; you need to run the command and immediately after uninstall the extension (with a reload). If you only run the command, you will eventually get Rickrolled again, even after uninstalling it, as I mentioned before.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).